# Node.js-like firebase module for Parse cloud code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, firebase

I'm trying to integrate Firebase with Parse to add real-time capabilities to my application. However, some API functions (like the ability to limit queries to Firebase with limit() or startAt()/endAt()) are not available with the firebase REST API.

They are available with the Node.js module, but even though Parse Cloud support CommonJS-like modules, I'm not sure it's possible to integrate the Firebase node module without some major tweaking.

Any idea how I could access these functions, other than running my own node.js server with the Firebase plugin and using it to redirect my calls to firebase?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible. What you'll want to do is create a "Cloud Code Module" and wrap the Firebase tools you need. [They have a tutorial here](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-with-third-party-services)

It's pretty standard node.js structures. You put all your Firebase methods into `exports`, add an `initialize` method (this is where you'd probably do things like auth?), and you're off.

Wrapping Firebase isn't hard or lengthy. Here's [a gist that wraps Firebase in a promise structure](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/335395ee91ea3db154e7), for example. You could basically take the methods from that gist as a blueprint for wrapping them into Parse.

Answer (score 1):

I find it not easy, `firebase` is dependent on `faye-websocket` and in its turn requires other libs. We can make it work using "Cloud Code Module" but I don't like adding libs this way.

This is a request for Parse to support node modules, unfortunately the answer is a flat NO from them for now https://parse.com/questions/using-npm-modules-in-cloud-code.

Would appreciate any update on this. Thanks!